Clarifying Polarity Inversion for FT600Q-FT601Q
The Version 1.06 of the FT600Q-FT601Q IC Datasheet released a few weeks ago, this note has been added:

Supports RIDN/RIDP (SSRX+/-) pin swap (polarity inversion detection), but TODN/TODP (SSTX+/-) pin swap is not supported. This can help simplify PCB routing.

My understanding of USB 3.0 SuperSpeed signaling is that polarity inversion is handled entirely at the receiver side, with no special requirements on the transmitter. In light of this, could someone clarify the meaning of this note?
